# configure not finding include files

Tags: c++, linux, qt, configuration

I am setting up a cross-compile environment, to run on my x86_64 Linux, building for Arm 64 (raspberry). When I configure Qt open source I see;

```
Note: QtSerialBus: Cannot find linux/can.h and linux/can/raw.h Linux headers for socketCAN support.
```

I downloaded the full Qt from http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.15/5.15.2/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2.tar.xz and I made sure my sysroot contains:

```
/root/raspi/sysroot/usr/include/linux/can.h
```

Why is this not found? My configure command is:

```
./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/root/raspi/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.mpacbti-rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi- -sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtwayland -skip qtlocation -skip qtscript -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5 -no-use-gold-linker -v -no-gbm
```

I tried adding:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /root/raspi/sysroot/usr/include
```

to the qmake.conf but it has no effect

Comment: So you're actually working as root on your desktop?

Comment: I have elevated to root to set this up, to ensure I don't encounter permission problems.  Are you saying that is contributing to the include issue?  (Or are you about to give me some helpful advice about elevation)

Comment: If you set up the toolchain as root but are trying to use it from your normal account you'll most likely run into permission issues ... (be unable to access files under `/root`). But using root as a day to day account is generally considered a horrendously stupid idea because of the likelihood of accidentally rendering your machine unusable.

Comment: I have elevated to setup and prove it works only - ensuring no permission errors.  If it works I return to regular account.  Since I'm running as root it's likely not a permission problem.

Comment: Using root account is likely either causing or hiding the issue. Just compile as normal user. _If_ you do global `make install`, do only that using `sudo`. But only if you install to system directories (such as under `/usr` ).